# Dynamic tooltip in jQuery i.e., tooltip should be fetched from database?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I want to show tooltip for every textbox like help contents...

That tooltip msg should be editable in admin side. How do I do that?
Or are there any standard jQuery plugins for that... I am using Codeigniter.

Answer (score 2):

I've used qtip with some success in the past. It is a tooltip plugin for jquery. Check it out here: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/

I am in no way affiliated with them.

As for how to provide the tool tip content, that is situation specific. I have often gotten them from a database, sometimes from other content on the form, etc. It is up to you, a database field is perfectly acceptable.

hth,

\ ^ / i l l